# Finding $y$ so that $y^2 + x^2 \equiv 1 (\mod x + y)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

A number of my friends at school came to me with the following problem which I was unable to solve. For any integer $x$, there exists $y$ so that:
$$ x^2 + y^2 \equiv 1 \mod x + y$$
I understand I am trying to solve for two integers $y$ and $q$ so that:
$$x^2 + y^2 = r(x+y) +1$$
However, I was unable to proceed much beyond this. Experimentally, I was able to compute $y$ and $q$ for a few values of $x$ but I wasn't able to identify and patterns in these values.

Comment: You can always take $y=1-x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By $x^2+y^2\equiv -2xy\pmod{x+y}$, we are really asking for $y$ such that $x+y \mid 2xy+1$. But $x\equiv -y\pmod{x+y}$, so this is equivalent to finding $y$ such that $$x+y \mid 2x^2-1.$$

The existence of such a $y$ and its possible values should be clear now: for any divisor $d$ of $2x^2-1$, $y = d-x$ works. In particular, taking $d=1$ and $d=2x^2-1$ show that $y = 1-x$ and $y = 2x^2-x-1$ both work everytime.